# If X is a random variable how do we show that $E(|X|)=0 \iff P(X=0)=1$

Tags: probability

If X is a random variable how do we show that $E(|X|)=0 \: \iff \: P(X=0)=1$

I see that $-|X|\le X \le |X|$ and so $|E(X)| \le 0$ and thus $E(X)=0$ but how do I show that this implies $P(X=0)=1$.

Comment: @Oracle Please avoid unnecessary edits to old questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, $|X|\geq 0$. So if $|X|$ is positive with non-zero probability, can the expected value be $0$?

Comment: Use $P(|X|\ge\epsilon) \le E(|X|)/\epsilon$.

Answer (score 0):

If $X$ is discrete, then the expectation you are looking for is:
$$
E(|X|)=\sum |x|Pr(X=x).
$$
What properties of $Pr(X=x)$ can you use to show that this is equal to 0 if and only if $Pr(X=0)=1$?

(If $X$ is continuous, it is not very different.)

Comment: And if $X$ is neither discrete nor continuous?

Comment: @StefanHansen Then I wouldn't know what to do. But in many cases (admittedly, hard to tell here) it would be enough to cover the continuous and discrete situations.